# My web view video plays in samsung tab but not in phone

Tags: android, webview, flvplayback, notsupportedexception

I have created a web view and used a embedded flv video link as for the video link. I was able to play it in my samsung tab but when i try to play it in my samsung phone all is shows is a BLUE LEGO WITH QUESTION MARKS.. What is the reason that i could play it in my tab but not in phone.

This is my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.webvideo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;  
private LinearLayout mContentView;
private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.fortunagate.com/adaderana_apps/video_player.php?video=http://derana.lk/content/video/SriGauthamaSambuddha24-15thJune2014.flv");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient  {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            private View mCustomView;

             @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
            {
                // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
                if (mCustomView != null)
                {
                    callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                    return;
                }

                // Add the custom view to its container.
                mCustomViewContainer.addView(view, COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER);
                mCustomView = view;
                mCustomViewCallback = callback;

                // hide main browser view
                mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Finally show the custom view container.
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCustomViewContainer.bringToFront();
            }

        }); 

      webview.loadUrl(url);

      return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

} 
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >




<LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

     <WebView
           android:id="@+id/webView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webvideo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.webvideo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would seem that your phone doesn't have Flash Player installed/enabled.

Comment: is there a way to play these kinds of videos without asking the device to install flash players?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Flashplayer installed on your Phone?
I had to install an older Flash Version on my Device, as Adobe stopped Support for Android a while ago, FLV Playback in Webview doesn't work with newer Android Versions.

Comment: is there a way to play these kind of video links (embedded flv videos ) in a web view without flash in the device?

Comment: Not in a Webview. You could of course start a video player with an intent, but that would also require the user to have an app installed that plays flv. So it's Flashplayer or Videoplayer, I don't know, how you can play flv natively in your app.